# Unable to compile latest Varnish on Debian 6

Tags: linux, debian, varnish, debian-squeeze

I just cloned the latest varnish git-repository to try and apply an enhancement (from git://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache.git)

All the dependencies listed on the website have been installed.

I run the following commands:
`./autogen.sh` -> works fine

`./configure` -> works fine too

`make` -> fails with the following error:

```
creating libvmod_std.la
(cd .libs && rm -f libvmod_std.la && ln -s ../libvmod_std.la libvmod_std.la)
========================================
You need rst2man installed to make dist
========================================
make[3]: *** [vmod_std.3] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/varnish-cache/lib/libvmod_std'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/varnish-cache/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/varnish-cache'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried installing rst2man but it cannot be found since it's a virtual package?:

```
apt-get install rst2man
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package rst2man
```

Then I tried installing the python-docutils but that also did not solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT:**

Commands I have ran after reading the answer:

I rebooted (first git clone is now gone since it was located in the /tmp directory)

```
cd /usr/share/
git clone git://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache.git
apt-get install python-docutils
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

=> Same error ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you installed python-docutils successfully make sure you clean the varnish sourcetree configuration cache and run configure again. make will then have what he needs (rst2man program, that is)

made a test. ran configure/make without rst2man, got the error. after installing python-docutils, I ran again configure which went fine, snip:

```
eu-we1:~/tmp/Varnish-Cache# ./configure |grep rst
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for rst2man... rst2man
checking for rst2html... rst2html
configure: WARNING: libedit not found, disabling libedit support
configure: WARNING: won't look for sendfile() on i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

make ran OK , exit code = 0
I guess you just need to make sure rst2man and probably rst2html as well (not sure) are found by configure script.
I verified with a varnish git clone .

Comment: And how would I do that? I always do a "make clean" after it fails. Any other command I should run to clean the sourcetree configuration cache?

Comment: remove any config.cache. if you use autogen to generate the configure script then run it again. the run ./configure. finally make should find rst2man.

Comment: usually make clean will remove any make generated files. if there's a make distclean target that should remove any configure generated files as well. if u remove config.cache, run again autogen,configure and make things should work ok, at least it will fix the current make error you encounter.

Comment: Just ran make clean , make distclean , autogen.sh , configure. While running make I bump across the same error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: maybe you hit a but in the repo code. do ./configure --with-rst2man=/usr/bin/rst2man --with-rst2html=/usr/bin/rst2html or ./configure --without-rst2man --without-rst2html

Comment: updated post with a current build

Comment: Updated first post too :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1756/discussion-between-sysfault-and-kenny)