# Errors while compiling Varnish 3 on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, varnish

I am new to linux and ubuntu and it is my first time to compile anything on linux. I am trying to compile varnish on ubuntu 14.10, but i got the following errors:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rst2man", line 21, in <module>
    from docutils.core import publish_cmdline, default_description
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/core.py", line 20, in <module>
    from docutils import frontend, io, utils, readers, writers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/frontend.py", line 41, in <module>
    import docutils.utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import docutils.io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>
    from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>
    locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
Makefile:735: recipe for target 'vmod_std.3' failed
make[3]: *** [vmod_std.3] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/altaf/Desktop/varnish3/Varnish-Cache/lib/libvmod_std'
Makefile:389: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/altaf/Desktop/varnish3/Varnish-Cache/lib'
Makefile:489: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/altaf/Desktop/varnish3/Varnish-Cache'
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have read the following article, but it did not helped.

[Unable to compile latest Varnish on Debian 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/329647/unable-to-compile-latest-varnish-on-debian-6?newreg=bfb01f3c67064972a109413022b3e1a8)

For installation, i followed these steps:

https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/installation/install.html#compiling-varnish-from-source

Kindly help me with this issue.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8

Comment: Hi Nathan C, still got the same issue. On ubuntu i used command nano ~/.bash_profile and then i placed the two lines in it and saved the file. But still i got the error. Can you please advice in more details?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably not using a UTF-8 locale on your system.

You can temporarily work around this in your shell by setting your locale to a UTF-8 locale, for instance:

```
export LC_ALL=ur_PK.UTF-8
export LANG=ur_PK.UTF-8
```

Comment: Can you please advice how to do that?

Comment: But I already did!

Comment: I mean how i can use that two export lines? I am new to linux and ubuntu

Comment: Put in the first one, and then put in the next one.

Comment: Sorry if i am not able to understand, but where i have to put them, in which file?

Comment: Type that as a command in your shell. Copy and paste the first line and just hit enter. Then do the same for the second.

Comment: Got this message: bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (ur_PK.UTF-8)

Comment: Hm. I think your system is quite broken then, or it wasn't installed with the right locales. You can always [add the missing locales](http://askubuntu.com/q/76013/75668) if you have sudo access, otherwise contact your system administrator.

Comment: At the moment i am logged in as root user. I have just installed ubuntu on paralllels.